# Relationship between Affine definition of singular point and projective definition

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, singularity

> Let $C : F(X,Y,Z) = 0$ be a projective curve given by a homogeneous
>   polynomial $F \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$, and let $P \in \mathbb{P}^2$ be
>   a point.
>
> Prove that $P$ is a singular point of $C$ if and only if 
>   $$
>      \frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(P) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(P) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(P) = 0. $$

I'm very lost on this problem. I was trying to prove the forward direction by using the fact that if $P = [a,b,c]$ is a singular point on $C$ then $(a/c,b/c)$ is a singular point on the curve $C_0 : F[x,y,1] = 0$ but I have no idea how to relate the two.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$f(x,y)=F(x,y,1).$$
In the affine plane, $(a,b)$ is a singularity of $f=0$ iff
$$f(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)
=0.$$
That is equivalent to
$$F(a,b,1)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(a,b,1)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(a,b,1)=0.\tag{*}$$
But $F$ must be homogeneous of degree $n$ say, so it satisfies *Euler's identity*
$$X\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}+Y\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}
+Z\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}=nF.$$
Using Euler's identity, (*) is equivalent to
$$F(a,b,1)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(a,b,1)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(a,b,1)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(a,b,1)=0,$$
that is to
$$F(P)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(P)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(P)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(P)=0.$$

In characteristic zero, Euler's identity means that
$\partial F/\partial X=\partial F/\partial Y=\partial F/\partial Z=0$
implies $F=0$, so that singularity is equivalent to
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(P)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(P)
=\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}(P)=0.\tag{$\dagger$}$$
But in characteristic $p$ one can have ($\dagger$) holding without
$F$ being zero.